# Removing the down arrow on a toolbaritem menu

Tags: macos, swiftui

Is there any way to remove the down arrow on a toolbar item when you add a menu to it?
It defaults to:

[image]

I tried styling the menu, but it does not affect that button/image.

```
.toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
           Menu {
               Button(action: {}) {
                  Label("Create a file", systemImage: "doc")
               }

               Button(action: {}) {
                  Label("Create a folder", systemImage: "folder")
               }
           }
           label: {
               Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.menuIndicator(.hidden)` to your `Menu`.